# Can I use "yield return" on an mvc method if so how do I get data in ajax request?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iterator, yield-return

I can't find any information/question regarding this issue, I have a controller with a method that returns a yield return, I'm using ajax to do the request but all I get back is text, let me show you.

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable GetData(int par1, int par2)
{ 
    foreach(var data in GetData())
    {
        yield return data ; 
    }
}
```

This is the response I'm getting:

GetData_21

I'm calling the method like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                par1: 2,
                par2: 2
            },  
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result); 
            },
            failure: function () {
            }
        });
```

Comment: return `IEnumerable` of what type?

Comment: object would suffice

Comment: Then your method should be `IEnumerable<object>` not just `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work, and I just found out it's not even getting to the controller, I mean I can't debug

Comment: $.ajax uses `error:`, not `failure:`, so try tapping into that and seeing what error is returned...

Comment: there's no error, it's printing "GetData_21" at   console.log(result);